# Magento product not appearing in front end (via rapidflow)

Tags: magento

I loaded some new products via Rapid flow and its shown at back end but it doesn't appear at front end. The product's 
1. quantity is greater than zero, 
2. It is set as In Stock
3. Enabled
4. Assigned Category
5. Assigned to website

All these done via import, after clearing cache and reindexing the product doesn't show up in front end.
  But when I modify any of the parameters at product edit page it appears on front end after Reindexing. It seems like a cache problem, but I have tried refreshing the cache. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Double check your store id http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440047/magento-ce-1-7-0-2-imported-products-do-not-show-up-in-frontend

Comment: Yes, store id is given. We gave all needed information in import file. Strange thing is if I edit something like title,price,meta tag etc and after re-indexing product shows up. Seems to be a weird problem and struggling to find a fix.

Comment: What sort of caching technique / method are you using?

Comment: We are using Normal magento cache